# Casting bug with inherited functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have a doubt about casting in c++. I will explain it through an example. Imagine I have two classes:

```
class c1 {
  public:
  c1() {}

  double getHi() { return _hi; }  

private:
  double _hi = 2;
}

class c2 : c1 {
  public:
  c2() {}
}
```

Since c2 is a child of c1, it inherits the function getHi(). So you can call getHi with an instance of c2.

But what happen if you make this? :

```
c2* b = new c2();
cout << b->getHi() << endl;
cout << ((c1*)b)->getHi() << endl;
```

The first one will work. But not the second one. Why is this? Anyone can explain it to me?

Thanks

EDIT: It was an example. I made a typo while writing it.

Comment: You should post your actual class declarations. The present declarations cannot be compiled.

Comment: If you change `class` to `struct` in two places and add semicolons at the end of the two class definitions you get code that compiles. I don't know whether it still illustrates the problem.

Comment: First, `c2` is a *derivation* of `c1`; not a child. Second, the word is *'inherit'* (in this case inherits). Finally The second doesn't work for the same reason none of this works. Everything in both classes is private and thus cannot be accessed even by derived classes. You need public exposure and/or friendship. The private: modifier in `c1` is meaningless since that is the default access level and there is nothing in the class that changes that.

Comment: "will not work" is not a good error description ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since c2 is a child of c1, it heretates the function getHi()

First of all, you should say that `c2` "derives from", or "is a derived class of", or "inherits (privately, in your case) from" `c1`. Also, "inherits" is the right verb.

> But what happen if you make this?

In this case, the casting cannot be performed because you inherit privately from `c1`. Change the definition of `c2` as follows and you'll see the two calls to `getHi()` working exactly the same way (in this case):

```
class c2 : public c1 { };
//         ^^^^^^
//         This means that public members of c1 will become
//         public members of c2 as well. If you specify nothing,
//         public members of c1 will become private members of
//         c2
```

Notice, that you are also missing the semicolons after class definitions and, most importantly, the `public` access modifier in the definitions of `c1` and `c2`: without them, constructors will be `private`, so you won't be able to instantiate those classes at all:

```
class c1
{
public: // <== Don't forget this!
  c1() {} // Btw, why this? It does nothing
  double getHi() { return _hi; }
private:
  double _hi = 2;
}; // <== Don't forget this!

class c2 : public c1
//         ^^^^^^ Don'f forget this!
{
public: // <== Don't forget this!
    c2() {} // Btw, why this? It does nothing
}; // <== Don't forget this!

int main()
{
    c2* b = new c2();
    b->getHi();          // Compiles, calls c1::getHi();
    ((c1*)b)->getHi();   // Compiles, calls c1::getHi();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you declared `c2` makes `c1` a *private base* of `c1`: outside code cannot cast `b` to `c1` because of this.

To fix, make `c1` a public base:

```
class c2: public c1 {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad form to use c style casting with c++ code.  Use static_cast<> or perhaps dynamic_cast<> instead.  Beyond that, you have privately inherited from c1 in your example.  If you changed it to:

```
class c2 : public c1 {
```

it would probably work better.